# How to detect Azure Key Vaults and add IPs to its firewall upon creation?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I am trying to automatically detect the creation of Azure Key Vaults to then automatically add a set of IP addresses to its firewall. That is, the networking setting on key vaults is set to `Allow public access from specific virtual networks and IP addresses`.

I've been exploring Azure Automation, Functions, and Policy services to achieve this but, in the end, I am not 100% sure of which service is the most suitable.

After testing Azure Policy, I've managed to detect key vaults that are not compliant upon creation (i.e. not having the desired set of IPs). Now, I would like to add a set of IPs so I thought about using the `append` effect but it doesn't seem to add the IPs.

This is the piece of code I have in the `Then` section of the policy. (Note x.x.x.x is just the placeholder for the actual IP)

```
"then": {
    "effect": "append",
    "details": [
      {
        "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/networkAcls.ipRules[*].value",
        "value": {
          "value": "x.x.x.x/32",
          "action": "Allow"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Any suggestions as to why it might not work or if any other service could be better for this task? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you test if `field` should be `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/networkAcls.ipRules[*]` ? At least the example in docs seems to imply that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#append-examples (example 2).

Comment: That was it! `"field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/networkAcls.ipRules[*]` did the trick! Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `field` should be `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/networkAcls.ipRules[*]` Example in docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects#append-examples (example 2)